# Can't update object in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to update my table via EF 6 in my ASP.NET MVC 5 app.

I get no error message or exception, but nothing is saved to the database. I suspect the object isn't `IQueryable` and as such not tracked by EF (if my understanding is right).

```
public async Task Work(Plan newPlan)
{
    var existingPlan = await this._planQuery.GetPlan(112);

    if (existingPlan != null)
    {
        await this._planCommand.UpdatePlan(newPlan, existingPlan))
    }
}
```

And the 2 relevant methods are

```
internal async Task<Plan> GetPlan(int id)
{
    return await base.DataContext.Plans.SingleAsync(a => a.Id == id);
}

internal async Task<bool> UpdatePlan(Plan newPlan, Plan existingPlan)
{
    existingPlan.LastEditDate = DateTime.Now;
    existingPlan.PlanName = newPlan.PlanName;
    existingPlan.Website = newlan.Website;

    if (!await base.SaveToDatabase())
        return false;

     return true;
}
```

This is what I'm doing, and if I understand correct what I'm expecting:

1. Receive an object with various property values. This needs to update an existing database entry, currently hardcoded with 112 (for testing only)
2. See if the plan with ID 112 exists (it does). We'll name this `existingPlan`. I'm expecting EF tracks any updates to this
3. Since the plan exists, call `UpdatePlan`, providing the `newPlan` and the `existingPlan`
4. 'Map' the relevant new values from `newPlan` to `existingPlan`
5. Since EF should be tracking the existing plan (which has now been updated), simply save

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you run a SQL Trace against the database, what SQL (SELECT, UPDATE etc) statements are being submitted to it?

Comment: The retrieval happens via `_planQuery` and the update via `_planCommand` objects; are both sharing the same `DbContext`? If not, the `Plan` instance isn’t been changetracked on the `DbContext` handling the update.

Comment: Please add the remaining source code of your application/problem to your question. We don't know what `this._planQuery`, `this._planCommand` and `base.SaveToDatabase` is or where you open the context to your database. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how to ask questions which show your problem.

Comment: @pfx please move to an answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that the retrieval of the `Plan` instance occurs via a `_planQuery` object, whereas the update occurs via a `_planCommand` object.
Probably these don't share the same `DbContext` instance; if this is the case, the `Plan` instance is not being changetracked within the `DbContext` doing the update, so no update statement gets executed.

To solve, ensure that both retrieval and update occur via the same `DbContext` instance.